# Using KOMA-Script article with org-mode

Tags: koma-script, org-mode

I want to export a document from org-mode to latex with the KOMA-Script article class `scrartcl`.  I thought it was as easy as to switch from `article` to `book`.  So I put in my org file the following configuration (the doc is a subtree of a larger document):

```
:EXPORT_LATEX_CLASS: koma-article
:EXPORT_LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [11pt,twoside,a4paper]
```

However, after I do the export comand, I get the error message :

```
Unknown latex class `koma-article'
```

I couldn't imagine that koma classes were not automatically recognized by org-mode. I've done some research on the web and tried [this solution](http://orgmode.org/tmp/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html) but it didn't work.

What's wrong ?  Is there something obvious I'm not doing ?

Thanks for your help.

**Added information after a coment:** the correct name of the class is `scrartcl` and not `koma-article`. Actually I tried both names `koma-article` and `scrartcl`, but in both cases I get the same error message.

Comment: Yes you're right. Actually I tried both "koma-article" and "scrartcl", but in both cases I get the same error message.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I added the codes to my .emacs. But when I evaluate it, I get error messages. For the `(require 'org-latex)` code: `"cannot open load file: no such a file, org-latex"` (I translate, in my pc it is in french). For the `(add-to-list…)` code, I see: `"symbol's value as variable is void: org-export-latex-classes"`. I didn't know I should install packages in order to export to a Koma class. Maybe it would be easier just to change it manually once the doc is exported...

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes I deleted comment, thanks

Comment: Try it with `(require 'ox-latex)` and `(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes '...)`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati: Yes it works, thanks.  So the correct code for the list, in which we must add the scrartcl class, is `org-latex-classes`, and **not** `org-export-latex-classes` as said in the org-mode website. Anyway I wonder why koma-script is not included by default in the org-mode recognized classes list, since it is widely used as an alternative to the latex standard classes. Thank you everybody for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [org manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#LaTeX-header-and-sectioning):

> By default, the LaTeX output uses the class `article`.
>
> You can change this globally by setting a different value for
>   `org-latex-default-class` or locally by adding an option like
>   `#+LATEX_CLASS: myclass` in your file, or with a `EXPORT_LATEX_CLASS`
>   property that applies when exporting a region containing only this
>   (sub)tree. The class must be listed in `org-latex-classes`. This
>   variable defines a header template for each class, and allows you to
>   define the sectioning structure for each class. You can also define
>   your own classes there.

`org-latex-classes` is an association list with LaTeX classes and associated header and structure.  Hence, you have to add your `koma-article` to this list.  I suggest you put something like this in your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "ox-latex"
  '(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
                '("koma-article" "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
                  ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                  ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                  ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                  ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                  ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```

If you're using Emacs 24.4. or later, you can use:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "ox-latex"
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
               '("koma-article" "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
                 ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                 ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```