# koma-article is defined in org-latex-classes but not ava

Tags: koma-script, emacs, org-mode

I tried the suggestion at: [Using KOMA-Script article with org-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364914/using-koma-script-article-with-org-mode)

When I try to export from an org file to LaTeX document class koma-article I get the message unknown LaTeX class 'scrartcl'.

Here is a MWE.

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: scrartcl
#+latex_class_options:

#+title: Mininum Working Example

* Opening Statement

 This is a minimal working example.
```

The following is in my init.el

```lisp
(require 'ox-latex)
(with-eval-after-load "ox-latex"
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("koma-article" "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
               ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
               ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```

I've inspected 'org-latex-classes and the koma-article data is in there.

Exporting to a LaTeX file with article class works. I can then change the class to scrartcl in TeX mode and create a pdf. It works, but I was wondering if there is a way to skip that step.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried: `#+LATEX_CLASS: koma-article`? I don't know org-mode, but I think, the name used for the `org-latex-class` should be used in the org-mode-document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the docstring of `org-latex-classes`:

> `org-latex-classes` is a variable defined in `ox-latex.el`.
>
> Alist of LaTeX classes and associated header and structure. If
> `#+LATEX_CLASS` is set in the buffer, use its value and the associated information.  Here is the structure of each cell:
>
> ```
> (class-name  
>   header-string
>   (numbered-section . unnumbered-section)
>   ...)
> ```

First entry in each list is the `class-name` which is the name you set with the `#+LATEX_CLASS:` in your .org file.  So if you want to use the `scrartcl`, the entry in your init file should look like this:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "ox-latex"
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
               '("scrartcl" "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
                 ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                 ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))))
```

Note that you don't need the form `(require 'ox-latex)` when you use `with-eval-after-load`.